# Is there any case where single quote or double quote is still required for JavaScript since we have template literals (backtick quote)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

With the introduction of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for JavaScript, it has much advantage over single quote and double quote as per mentioned in https://ponyfoo.com/articles/template-literals-strictly-better-strings.

In term of performance, there's no obvious different between them as stated in https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/are-backticks-slower-than-other-strings-in-javascript-ce4abf9b9fa

So my question is, is there any case where [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) can't be used other than the case of printing `"Testing ${something}"` where then back-tick need a slash as in `` `Testing \${something}` ``

I have checked various related existing Stackoverflow

- [JavaScript ES6, backticks or quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089057/javascript-es6-backticks-or-quotes)
- [Is there a downside to using ES6 template literals syntax without a templated expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777677/is-there-a-downside-to-using-es6-template-literals-syntax-without-a-templated-ex)
- [Should we use backticks to quote string literals now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43086467/should-we-use-backticks-to-quote-string-literals-now)

From the stackoverflows, can't see anything that shows a single quote or double quote is required that can't be achieved by backtick, other than stating it as easier distinguish the different purpose.

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance, my findings as below https://stackoverflow.com/a/59597360/3286489, let me know if my findings is incorrect?

Comment: Well, what makes you think there is any case where backticks are "required" (that can't be achieved single or double quotes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I found is, the following can't use backtick

1. Object declaration

```
                const headers2 = {
                    `Accept`: `application/json`,
                    `Content-Type`: `application/json`
                };
```

This will error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected template string`

2. Importing module

```
import React from `react`;
```

This will error stating `Parsing error: Unexpected token`

Not sure if my findings are legit or there are more cases. Feel free to share.

**Updated**
3. Using of `use strict`

```
    `use strict`;
```

The above is not functioning without any warning.

Comment: I suppose template strings may be less performant compared to string literals, and as you noticed, can't be used in some cases.

Comment: Thanks @KooiInc. As mentioned in https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/are-backticks-slower-than-other-strings-in-javascript-ce4abf9b9fa, performance differences is negligible.

Comment: Thanks for the link! So, as long as there's nothing to interpolate, backticks are fine. In that case you can use them for properties like this: `{[\`someKey\`]: \`someValue\`}`

Comment: Thanks @KooiInc. I also found a supporting gist stating my findings https://gist.github.com/getify/105df0a0c17892243a37c4fced1d3a8b